# Breaking down the $[-π/5 , π/5]$ interval in to values to solve for $r=cos(5\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I had a more or less similar question, and I marked it as solved, because at that moment it was indeed solved  - I was correctly advised and explained how to proceed. So this question is not a duplicate, and it refers more to computations than to the polar equation  $r=\cos(5\theta)$ per se.

**My goals is to learn how to pick angles in the given range, and then compute r, x, y, which should be go smoothly, I assume, once I have correct angles.**

Please, advice me and help me to understand once and for all my mistakes, as I do unexpectedly struggle with finding correct values of $\theta$, and thus $r$, $x$ and $y$, in the range $[-π/5 , π/5]$ - that is I don't understand if I pick correct values from $[-π/5,0]$, and from $[0$ to $π/5]$. I find that values don't seem to form anything close to the beautiful rose, which $r=\cos(5\theta)$ represents.

Here is a screen shot from excel table to show only the beginning of my computations.

EDIT: I have changed the picture because I had a typo in the previous one.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: The third line of your spread sheet $\theta= \frac{-\pi}{10} $ & then you use the value $ \frac{- \pi}{6}$ ? ... Not entirely understanding what you want as answer ? Will a table of values suffice ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thank you very much for pointing out my typo. I have corrected the spreadsheet. I need to learn how to determine correct values of $\theta$, and for now I seem to fail. If I need angles in the given range, then I need to find values of $\theta$ between -π/5 and π/5, but the values I picked up are arbitrary, not based on the understanding, or any correct algorithm, and that is a flaw, which I want to correct. I also seem to get wrong values - based on these x and y I don't see a nice rose coming (I have this table extended; a shorter version here for everyone's convenience)

Comment: You will need a larger range of $ \theta $ values, try $ \frac{-10 \pi}{100} ,\frac{-9 \pi}{100},\frac{-8 \pi}{100} \cdots \frac{-1 \pi}{100} ,0,\frac{ \pi}{100} \cdots \frac{8 \pi}{100} ,\frac{9 \pi}{100},\frac{10 \pi}{100} $ ... this should give you $20$ ($21$ ?) points on the first petal of the rose

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you, please, explain how you have chosen these values. My main concern is how to choose, determine, find values that would be correct for a particular graph. Is there an algorithm I missed?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f4aq76h6f7 ... The equation $r=\cos (5 \theta)$ will contain $5$ peaks & troughs ... The points indicated in blue & green correspond to $ \frac{ \pm \pi}{10}$ ... there will be $10$ petals ...